# AT91SAM7A3 not in kit list in Atmel Studio 6.2

Tags: atmel, atmel-studio

I am trying to use Atmel Studio 6.2 and Atmel ICE to program AT91SAM7A3, but I could not find AT91SAM7A3 in the kit list of Atmel Studio 6.2.
What should I do next if I want to load my code in AT91SAM7A3?

Comment: try http://www.keil.com/dd/chip/3821.htm

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestions.                             Are there any ways we can add the device file in ATMEL Studio 6.2? or any other Atmel software support both Atmel ICE and AT91SAM7A3?